# How can I enable responsive font weight adjustment in Elementor?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, elementor

## How can I add the Elementor responsive option to the typography weight?

I would like to enable the responsive option for the 'Font Weight' feature in Elementor. Currently, there is no such option available, preventing me from adjusting the font weight for different breakpoints."

I tired to read their documentation but not solved, If I add in the "plugins/elementor/includes/controls/groups/typography.php" by default the code is like below:

```
$fields['font_weight'] = [
    'label' => esc_html_x('Weight', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
    'type' => Controls_Manager::SELECT,
    'default' => '',
    'options' => [
        '100' => '100 ' . esc_html_x('(Thin)', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        '200' => '200 ' . esc_html_x('(Extra Light)', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        '300' => '300 ' . esc_html_x('(Light)', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        '400' => '400 ' . esc_html_x('(Normal)', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        '500' => '500 ' . esc_html_x('(Medium)', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        '600' => '600 ' . esc_html_x('(Semi Bold)', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        '700' => '700 ' . esc_html_x('(Bold)', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        '800' => '800 ' . esc_html_x('(Extra Bold)', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        '900' => '900 ' . esc_html_x('(Black)', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        '' => esc_html_x('Default', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        'normal' => esc_html_x('Normal', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
        'bold' => esc_html_x('Bold', 'Typography Control', 'elementor'),
    ],
];
```

And if I add:

```
'responsive' => true,
```

After the 'options' array, then the responsive options show on the elementor.
But I want to use my custom plugin fo extend the class and add the functionality.
Elementor hook docs : https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/php/